# How to compare resultsets of two different databases?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have two databases and i need to compare three rows from each database if they are matches, I have to print that row.

Example:

```
Database 1:
RuleId  Dataset  Partition  Date
------  -------  --------   ----
1234     ABVD    012145    21/01/2014
1256     ABCD    124565    22/01/2013
4567     FGHJ    0123456  22/02/2013
Database 2:
1234    ABCD    012345    21/01/2014
4567    FGHJ    0123456   22/02/2013
7894    MNBV    0147896   20/01/2014
```

If RuleId,Dataset and Partition are equal in both databases I have to print those rows in output.

My Code is as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> rslist = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> rs1list = new ArrayList<String>();
int count = 1;
while (rs.next()) {
    int i = 1;
    count = 1;
    while (i < count) {
        rslist.add(rs.getString(i++));
    }

    rslist.add(rs.getString(2) + rs.getString(4) + (rs.getString(5)));

}
int count1 = 1;
while (rs1.next()) {
    int i = 1;
    count1 = 1;
    while (i < count1) {
        rs1list.add(rs1.getString(i++));

    }
    rs1list.add(rs1.getString("RuleId") + rs1.getString("Dataset")
            + rs1.getString("Partition"));
}
for (String s1 : rslist)
    for (String s2 : rs1list)
        if (s1.equals(s2)) {

        }
```

If these rows are equal I have to print all the row values.

Comment: I have to compare 6 resultset values at a time and if they are matching then I have to print that full row

Comment: Isn't your current code doing this? it seems to do the job.

Comment: Actually there are more columns in the database in that I'm just comparing three columns only. In my code it will show only combined value. I have to print whole row.

Comment: what is this code for `    int i = 1;
    count = 1;
    while (i < count) {
        rslist.add(rs.getString(i++));
    }`

Comment: It will go for row wise and add to arraylist

Comment: i and count both are equal so your condition to while will never be true.

Comment: You load all in memory and then compares. For big tables that could be a problem. You can have perfectly more than one JDBC connection in your program and go thru both record sets at same time without storing in memory.

Comment: Peter could u tell me with small example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ResultSet is a subclass of Object ultimately and we can compare two or more objects directly.
A little specific to your question:

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql1);
ResultSet rs1=st.executeQuery(sql2);
```

where sql1 and sql2 are 2 Statements

```
while(rs.next() && rs1.next()){
         int a=rs.next();
         int b=rs1.next();
         if(a==b){
              System.out.println("Compairing two ResultSets");
         }
     }
```

Comment: rs.next() returns boolean not int! how can you compare them?

Comment: It's 7 years later and I can't stop laughing how wrong this is. Please don't do this.

Answer (score 1):

In your `executeQuery()` method, you can use the following SQL command:

```
select * from db1,db2 where db1.ruleid=db2.ruleid and db1.dataset=db2.dataset and db1.partition=db2.partition;
```

Then you can get the matched rows which are presented in both databases.

Answer (score 0):

Example (from scratch) for comparing without pre-loading in memory:

```
    Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db1", "user", "pass");
    Connection con2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db2", "user", "pass");

    Statement stmt1 = con1.createStatement();
    Statement stmt2 = con2.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("select * from ... order by ... ");
    ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery("select * from ... order by ... ");

    while(rs1.next() && rs2.next()) {
        // compare basically rs1.getObject(i).equals(rs2.getObject(i))
    }
```

Or read from db1 and then retrieve witk PK from db2. I don't know your use-case ...

Answer (score 0):

If the data sizes are not massive, I would suggest fully loading datasets and comparing in memory as follows.

Define class to represent a record implementing `equals`, which provides the logic of comparing fields element by element

```
public class Record {
    ...
    public boolean equals(Object record) {
        ...
```

Load both datasets into a `Set` each (rather than `ArrayList`, although the latter will work as well, or a `LinkedHashSet` if your want order) and use set operations to check if elements present in both or if one is subset of another etc.

The other suggested approaches assume very well formed sets with distinct order, no duplications, no in-between insertions (A,C vs A,B,C) etc.